# Need to capture popup menu keyboard input. MFC dialog

Tags: mfc, dialog

I have a MFC dialog application with two bitmap. When the bitmap are clicked a popup menu will appear for the user.  I am now trying to add keyboard support. I am able to trap the F10 key to bring up one of the menus. The Esc is handled by the menu. But I need to handle the left and right arrow keys to bring up the other menu. Does anyone know how to handle this?

Comment: [Jerry Coffin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35000514/1889329) is the way to go (really, why reinvent the wheel). If you insist on rolling your own, see [Writing your own menu-like window](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040820-00/?p=38103).

Answer (score 2):

Since you apparently want the two bitmaps to act like the top level of a menu, I'd define it as menu with with the two bitmaps associated with the two menu items (see MF_BITMAP and/or MIIM_BITMAP).

The [MSDN Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647558.aspx#_win32_Using_Menu_Item_Bitmaps) gives the basic ideas involved.

Comment: I added code to OnInitDialog and the behavior is just what I want. The problem is does not look good. The bitmaps look OK but the menu bar alongside does not look good. Is there a way to change the menu bar color?

Comment: @dlb: You can certainly change the color by responding to WM_NCPAINT. At a guess, you may just want to change the painting of that menu bar to...just return without paining anything (and possibly just change the other processing to say it's not a menu bar in the first place).